# Extract cookie value from request (POSTMAN/JMETER)

Tags: rest, jmeter, postman

How can I Extract these three cookies from a request and pass them as headers in second request

First Request:
[image: First request]

Second Request:
[image: Second request]

Comment: Have you tried capturing the cookie value as an environment variable to use in the next request?

Comment: What issue exactly you are facing with JMeter to solve this?

Comment: @DannyDainton i have wrote this piece of code in tests "pm.environment.set(XCSRF_Token, pm.Get-Cookie("XCSRFToken").Value());" which is failing to extract value

Comment: @Amol With Jmeter Cookie Manager, its sending cookie in second request but still i was getting error of un-authorized user

Comment: I guess you need to extract the cookie first and then set up in Header Manager. you tried that?

Comment: Feel free to upvote too if it's useful :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using the [pm.cookies.get()](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/scripts/postman_sandbox_api_reference) function to extract the cookie values that you require:

[image: Postman Docs]

This can then be set in an `environment` or `global` variable and using it in any request you want.

This is an example using the [jsonplaceholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com) site and logging the cookie value to the Postman console.

[image: Postman]

You could then use the `pm.environment.set('my_cookie', pm.cookies.get('cookie_value'))` function and store it as an environment variable. This can then be used in the next/any request's `Header` by referencing it with the `{{my_cookie}}` syntax.

[image: Postman]

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working for me.
The env variable gets created, but is empty.
When I output pm.cookies.get("my_cookie") it prints _null_ on the console.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

For JMeter:

1. Add the next line to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   CookieManager.save.cookies=true
   ```
2. Restart JMeter to pick the property up.

   This way JMeter will store all cookie values as [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html).
3. Add [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) as a child of the 2nd request and configure it as follows:

   - Name: `XCSRFToken`
   - Value: `${COOKIE_XCSRFToken}`

     [image: JMeter Cookies As a Header]

See [HTTP Cookie Manager Advanced Usage - A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-cookie-manager-advanced-usage-a-guide) article for more HTTP Cookie Manager tips and tricks.