# How can I call a GET endpoint from Postman with JSESSIONID and CSRF protection enabled?

Tags: cookies, csrf, web-api-testing, jsessionid

My cookies in the request header look like this:
[website cookies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mt4Z6.png)

When I log out or the session expires, I can't make a GET request in Postman, because the values of those two are different each time.

I don't know how to generate csrf token and jsessionid and include them in the response header section of Postman automatically so I can use them without adding them manually.

Will be grateful if someone helps me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a valid login-request and have Postman automatically use the `JSESSIONID` and `CSRF-TOKEN` in the following request as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49190911/extract-cookie-value-from-request-postman-jmeter).

The JSESSIONID should be set as a cookie, and the CSRF-TOKEN should probably be set as a header value.